# Apt-get update error after fresh installed 16.04 LTS Desktop

Tags: apt, 16.04, updates

I try to install a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop, but `apt-get update` can not find repository:

```
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages
```

A manual check with Browser Show:

```
Packages.gz
Packages.xz
```

with change date from today (2016-08-23) but no "Packages" Folder.

Comment: Please provide the exact and complete output of `apt-get update`. (By the way, you can also use the arguably better `apt update`.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem. looks like a bug in the install Assistent (pointing to not existant repository). 
If i choose the "install 3rd party drivers" option during the installation preparation sequence, the error appears. 
If i skip it, i have no problem after installation is finish.

Problem Status: solved.

So i will install ubuntu without 3rd party drivers and install it later.
It was the first time i try this choice.
I has start with ubuntu 4 days ago, before i had used debian, because i'm a German.